# Database design for categorized to-do app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm trying to figure out what the best (most logical) way of designing this database for an app that will allow a user to CRUD to-do tasks (more or less), however, they're organized into hard-coded categories.

So let's say you're about to go to your favorite department store. You need to hit up the **Women's floor** and pick up your girlfriend the shoes she ordered, and the matching dress (which is on the completely other side of the store, but on the same floor.) Then, you need to go to the **Boy's department** for your little brother, and pick up two different pairs of shorts, one pair of pants, and a new pair of shoes.

The Women's Floor and Boy's Department are two examples of categories that the shopping list items will fall into.

So it looks like this:

```
* Women's Floor
     1 Pair Shoes
     1 Dress

* Boy's Department
     2 Shorts
     1 Pant
     1 Pair Shoes
```

So my database design could look like so...

```
Categories: id, title
ListIndex: id, user_id
ShoppingList: id, listindex_id, category_id, item_id, order, active
Items: id, name, category_id
```

Categories would be Boy's Department, Women's Floor, etc. Users would not be able to create new categories, but instead, we would predefine the categories

ListIndex would provide a master relation to the shopping list as a whole.

ShoppingList would be the actual shopping list (active would be 0/1, so the user could have a way to remind themselves that they bought the item / put it in their cart.)

Items would have a list of items that are available to put into the to-do tasks. We would categorize these ourselves on the back-end.

Is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: This sounds fine, except i can't see why ListIndex necessary?

Comment: @jokklan So that there's one master list for each list as a whole.

Comment: What do you mean by one master list? I'm pretty sure you should be able to do whatever you want without ListIndex, it looks like unnecessary bloat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully i understood the description of the problem correctly but i was thinking here's one way you could lay your database and models out.  I also don't think you need the ListIndex:

Database Tables

```
Categories: id, title

ShoppingLists: id, user_id, order, active

Items: id, title

ShoppingListItems: id, item_id, shopping_list_id, quantity

CategorizedItems: id, category_id, item_id

Users: id, name
```

Models

```
User:
has_many shopping_lists

ShoppingList:
belongs_to user
has_many shopping_list_items
has_many items, through shopping_list_items

Items:
has_many categorized_items
has_many categories, through categorized_items
(optional: you could query an item for the shopping lists that it is on)
has_many shopping_list_items
has_many shopping_lists, through shopping_list_items

Categories:
has_many categorized_items
has_many items, through categorized_items
```

My thinking is this --

Individual categories are basically static, that's pretty straight forward.
Shopping lists represent a User's (via the user_id) list of items that will be purchased.  The link between an item and a shopping list could take place in a join table called ShoppingListItems where each row links together the relationship between a list, an item, and the quantity.

Items are interesting because in your example an item is something that can actually be in multiple categories.  i.e. "pants" can be in boys/girls/men/women and probably pets :(. To support that I think you can use another join table called CategorizedItems that basically lets you query for "items in a particular category" or "categories an item is in".

Comment: You sir deserve a gold star. But I can give you a green check. Thanks for the super detailed explanation. karma_points belong_to mariozig.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate it. If you find anything i mentioned is erroneous please comment. i didn't actually test/code out that stuff.

Comment: Don't even worry about it. I was more or less looking someone to validate it conceptually. And that you did. :)